# How to compile all packages ROS with debug info?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to debugging the node "nxt_assisted_teleop" in Eclipse. I've written in the file CMakeList.txt in line 10 "set (ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)", but I got an run-time error:

*assisted_teleop: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/eigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/UnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.*

I think it's because of what other nodes are compiled without debug info. I want to try to compile all packages with debug information. How to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10255/how-to-compile-all-packages-ros-with-debug-info?/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely not conceptually related to compiling in debug mode, but rather an issue in in using Eigen types. Eigen has special requirements for use because of the optimization it uses. Compiling in debug probably just brought the problem to the surface.

Are you running only ROS code, or is anything your own?

There is a possibility that this is a ROS bug, but if you have any of your own code involved, I'd definitely follow the link provided in the error message check that against your own code first.

If it's ROS code then it would be wise to file a [bug report](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/) (user accound needed).

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-14**:
You can create an account at https://code.ros.org/gf/?

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2011-06-14**:
Thank you! I am running only ROS code. I'll try to find bug. I do not have a user account for bug report.